# Issue after importing video in Premiere

Tags: video, audio, mp4, premiere-pro

I imported some videos in Premiere Pro (MOV format, captured with iPhone), but after adding them to the timeline, they start to have issues, like video and sound not sync, and videos that repeat themself  (i.e. they start again from the beginning after 15s). It is quite annoying, I tried changing the format to mp4 but I have the same issue. Of course the original files are not corrupt and play properly in any video player.

I also tried to export the project in a video file, and it also shows the same behavior, so it is not just a playback bug in Premiere Pro.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use any video converter and convert your files to constant frame rate.
Handbrake, movavi video converter, ffmpeg, xvid4psp or any other.

For ffmpeg your command line will be similar:

```
ffmpeg -i "input-file-name.mov" -r 25 "output-file-name.mov"
```

`-r 25` - it's a framerate.

Mediainfo should show constant frame rate after render.
[image]

Comment: Awesome, problem solved, thank you very much!